# Adding Prime numbers and Fibonacci numbers

Tags: python, numbers, fibonacci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out 20th, 30th, nth prime number. (I’m getting 20th but not 30th?) [Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995890/find-out-20th-30th-nth-prime-number-im-getting-20th-but-not-30th-python)
>   [Fastest way to list all primes below N in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n-in-python)

prime numbers :

```
P=[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, …]
```

fibonacci numbers :

```
F=[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, …]
```

i want the user to give a random number between (1,100000) and the program to summarize the result `(F[n]+P[n])`for example if `n=3` `F[3]+P[3]=7+2=9`

i have written the following code :

```
import math
def F(n):
    return int(((1+math.sqrt(5))**n-(1-math.sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*math.sqrt(5)))
L=[]
L.append(2)
L=[]
for n in range(2, 10000):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            break
    else:
        # loop fell through without finding a factor
        L.append(n)

while True:
    x = raw_input().strip()
    if x == "END" or x == "end":
        break
    else:
        num = int(x)
        print F(num)+L[num]
```

it easy for me to find the Fib numbers just from the def F(n) ,but creating the prime numbers list is really a headache cause as the numbers increase it take some time for the list to be created,and making almost impossible to reach the n into those huge numbers..i tried to make a def not to creating the list butjust calculating the  prime number just for the n provided by the user.any ideas??

thank you in advance!

Comment: The question essentially boils down to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995890/find-out-20th-30th-nth-prime-number-im-getting-20th-but-not-30th-python

Comment: Algorithms to generate prime numbers are older than computers. Did you do any research?

Comment: Use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to get a list of primes. It's a very fast and simple algorithm to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Prime Numbers, there are several [primality tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) that you can implement. I like the naive methods, checking up to sqrt(n), there is also the Sieve of Erathostenes as Marcus Stuhr pointed out. You can optimize it a little bit if you check only the primality of odd numbers.